# Get Signed Download URL of pdf uploaded to Firebase Storage with Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

After much time spent on Google and countless hours of documentation reading, I've come here to place this question as I'm not making any more progress.

I'm trying to upload a file to Firebase Storage using a firebase function and then get the download url to send back at the finalization of the firebase function.

To start with, I've included the `firebase-admin` and `@google-cloud/storage` at the top of my `index.js`. And initialized them.

```
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert({ 
       // removed for security
       // This block was provided by Firebase Admin SDK 
       // under service accounts in settings of Firebase.
   }),
   databaseUrl: //removed for security,
   storageBucket: //removed for security
});
```

Then finally, my function that creates a firebase database record, generates a PDF and stores that file in firebase storage and then should return me a valid url to get the pdf.

```
exports.createInvoice = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        if(req.method == 'POST') {
            generateInvoiceNumber().then((number) => {
                req.body.number = number.number;
                req.body.created = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
                var total = 0;
                var items = req.body.items;
                for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    total = total + (items[i].cost * items[i].qty);
                }
                req.body.total = total.toFixed(2);
                admin.database().ref('invoices').push(req.body).then(function(response){
                    var html = // removed for brevity;
                    var file = admin.storage().bucket().file('/tmp/invoice-'+number.number+'.pdf');
                    htmlPdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream){
                        stream.pipe(file.createWriteStream());
                        //stream.on('finish', function(){
                            const config = {
                                action: 'read',
                                expires: '03-09-2491',
                                contentType: 'application/pdf'
                            };
                            admin.storage().bucket().file('tmp/invoice-'+number.number+'.pdf').getSignedUrl(config).then(signedUrls => {
                                res.status(200).send(signedUrls);
                            })
                        //});
                    });
                });
            }).catch(error => {
                res.status(500).send(error);
            })
        } else {
            res.status(405).send('Method Not Allowed');
        }
    });
});
```

The only portion that is not working correctly is the returned URL near the end of my function.

```
admin.storage().bucket().file('tmp/invoice-'+number.number+'.pdf').getSignedUrl(config).then(signedUrls => {
  res.status(200).send(signedUrls);
});
```

When I try to access the returned url in my browser, I get the following error.

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
```

Comment: I'm aware this question has been asked before on stackoverflow as I've tried many many answers on this platform already. Please don't flag as duplicate as they are not requiring the same answer, clearly because I've tried them previously.

Comment: Do you need to initialize the admin SDK with all those properties, or can you just take the default configuration that Cloud Functions provides for your project?  Unless you need to reach outside your project, you can just init with no parameters to get all the defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I'm doing because I'm using something like this, I found that the key you are looking for in the metadata, is mediaLink. Here is my code examp.

```
                  admin.storage().bucket().file(`home/home-carousel/${filename}`).save(file, (data) => {
                if(!data){
                  res(admin.storage().bucket().file(`home/home-carousel/${filename}`).getMetadata().mediaLink)
                }
              } )
```

The res() is the portion you want!

EDIT: getMetadata returns a promise you have to resolve in order to get metadata, if you don't to this, your mediaLink will be undefined. And, there are several arguments passed back from the promise, access them like an array, I provided a code example.

```
const saveLocation = storage.bucket('salesportal-8b7ef.appspot.com').file(`home/home-carousel/${webPFileName}`)
                  saveLocation.save(data, (stuff) => {
                    if(!stuff){
                      saveLocation.makePublic().then( () => {
                        saveLocation.getMetadata()
                        .then( (meta) => {
                          metadata = meta[0]
                            admin.firestore().collection("Pages").doc("home-carousel").set({ homeCarousel : {[`${filename}`] : { webPUrl : `${metadata.mediaLink}`}} }, {merge: true}).then( 
                              () => {
                                resolve()
                              })
                        })

                      })
                    }
```